# "m trying to echo a text into one line with no line breaks

Tags: php, nl2br

I"m trying to echo a text into one line with no line breaks. I've tried to use nl2br and than replace all /n or /r with nothing.
I want the output to be:

"I"m trying to write my text in one line"

instead of:

"I"m trying to write my text

in one line"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$mytext = 'I"m trying to write my text
in one line';  

$mytext = nl2br($mytext);
$mytext = preg_replace('/\r?\n|\r/','', $mytext);
$mytext = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),"", $mytext);
echo $mytext;

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than not using `nl2br`, and needing to replace with a space, not an empty string, your code should work fine (note you can optimise the `preg_replace` by using `\R` which matches any unicode newline sequence):

```
$mytext = "I'm trying to write my text\r
in one line";  

echo preg_replace('/\R/',' ', $mytext);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r","\n"), " ", $mytext);
```

Output:

```
I'm trying to write my text in one line
I'm trying to write my text in one line
```

Now if you want to make sure it remains on one line in the HTML, you need to replace spaces with non-breaking spaces e.g.

```
$mytext = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $mytext);
```

Here's a demo using `&nbsp;` in JS:

```js
let str = "I'm trying to write my text in one line I'm trying to write my text in one line I'm trying to write my text in one line";
$('#d1').html(str);
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
$('#d2').html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" style="width: 200px;"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `preg_replace` will do the trick. If the only character you need to replace is newlines, try the following:

```
$mytext = 'I"m trying to write my text
in one line';
echo preg_replace('/\n/', ' ', $mytext); // prints I"m trying to write my text in one line
```

Even though you don't explicitly include a newline character in your multi-line string, the line break will be interpreted as a newline character so you can identify it using `\n` in your regex.

The reason your current solution isn't working as expected is that `nl2br` inserts html line break elements into the string, not newline characters. See the docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php. When I run your solution it prints `I"m trying to write my text<br />in one line` - the newline characters are being removed, but not the html elements added by `nl2br`.

In the future, please include the incorrect output you're seeing in your post along with the code!